# Sort list of methods

Tags: java, sorting, reflection, collections

I have a list which contains all setters of my POJO class.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Method[] publicMethods = SampleClass.class.getMethods();
    List<Method> setters = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Method method : publicMethods){
        if (method.getName().startsWith("set") && method.getParameterCount() == 1) {
            setters.add(method);
        }
    }
}
```

In documentation order of Method list is not guaranteed.
My question is how can i sort my list of setters alphabetically?

Comment: Google for "how to sort objects in Java", click on one of the thousands of links you get, and read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a custom [comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html):

```
Collections.sort(setters, new Comparator<Method> {
  @Override
  public int compare(Method a, Method b) {
    return a.getName().compareTo(b.getName());
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that this way using java8 :

```
List<Method> setters = Arrays.asList( SampleClass.class.getMethods() )
.stream()
.filter(
  e->e.getName().startsWith("set")
).sorted(
  (a, b)->
        a.getName()
        .compareTo(b.getName())
).collect(Collectors.toList())
```